# django example - why are methods called on the .save() object?

Tags: python, django, forms, save

The following example is from this tutorial, and explains how to update passwords for users in django.  I have trouble understanding the following:

1)  Why is `user_form.save()` given a definition `(user = user_form.save())`?  Why can't we just call `user_form.save()`?

2)  Since user is defined as `user_form.save()`, why do we call the `set_password` method on user?  Shouldn't this be called on the `user_form itself`?

3)  We go on to call `user.save()`.  Doesn't this mean `user_form.save().save()`?  Isn't this redundant?

Thanks

http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/login.html

```
def register(request):
    # Like before, get the request's context.
    context = RequestContext(request)

    # A boolean value for telling the template whether the registration was successful.
    # Set to False initially. Code changes value to True when registration succeeds.
    registered = False

    # If it's a HTTP POST, we're interested in processing form data.
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Attempt to grab information from the raw form information.
        # Note that we make use of both UserForm and UserProfileForm.
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST)

        # If the two forms are valid...
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            # Save the user's form data to the database.
            user = user_form.save()

            # Now we hash the password with the set_password method.
            # Once hashed, we can update the user object.
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            # Now sort out the UserProfile instance.
            # Since we need to set the user attribute ourselves, we set commit=False.
            # This delays saving the model until we're ready to avoid integrity problems.
            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user

            # Did the user provide a profile picture?
            # If so, we need to get it from the input form and put it in the UserProfile model.
            if 'picture' in request.FILES:
                profile.picture = request.FILES['picture']

            # Now we save the UserProfile model instance.
            profile.save()

            # Update our variable to tell the template registration was successful.
            registered = True

        # Invalid form or forms - mistakes or something else?
        # Print problems to the terminal.
        # They'll also be shown to the user.
        else:
            print user_form.errors, profile_form.errors
```

Answer (score 1):

1.- `user = user_form.save()` Saves the Form only if this is a `ModelForm` the method save returns an instance of the model (new or existing) as

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')
```

its model is `User` this one returns an instance of the `User Model`, this is assigned to the `user` variable for using it afterward

2.- `user.set_password(user.password)` this sets the password

3.- `user.save()` this saves again the user.

Answer (score 0):

`ModelForm.save()` saves the model to the database as defined by the form's input elements. The method returns the appropriate (new or existing) model. We then operate further on the model to perform actions that *it* supports rather than the form. And then once we're done operating on the model, we save it again.

Comment: I didn't realize the save method returns the updated model, very useful to know.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1) if you don't plan on using the `user` name then its fine to just call `.save()` on the object. The tutorial may be self documenting - showing that a `user` object is returned from the `save` method.

2) we are setting the password for the `user` object. The `user_form` sure returns a `user` object - but its not nice for the reader to see `form.save().set_password()`. This is a readability thing IMO.

3) it is 2 database writes. Not sure why the tutorial chose to do this the way it has, it doesn't make much sense to me either, and the comments say what's going on, but not why its being done. Ask the author.

Note I'm not a fan of the code in the tutorial. It's far better to use [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/) when creating a object that always "come in 2s" (user *always* has a profile). Using signals we can trigger the automatic creation of a `UserProfile` when a `User` is created, which avoids a likely problem where a user may be created in another piece of code, or through the shell without a profile being created.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my answer is too late.

Before the answer, let me clarify:

First, your plain text shouldn't be directly stored in database for security reason, what is stored in the database is the encoded password. Obviously, Django provides the mechanism(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/passwords/) to encode the password.

Second, see how save() works:

["Every ModelForm also has a save() method. This method creates and saves a database object from the data bound to the form. A subclass of ModelForm can accept an existing model instance as the keyword argument instance; if this is supplied, save() will update that instance. If it’s not supplied, save() will create a new instance of the specified model"][1]

Third, see what is set_password():

["set_password(raw_password)
Sets the user’s password to the given raw string, taking care of the password hashing. Doesn’t save the User object. 
When the raw_password is None, the password will be set to an unusable password, as if set_unusable_password() were used."][2]
(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_password)

So let me answer your question now
Suppose you set your password to "abc"
When you first time call user_form.save(), an instance of User is saved to database, however, your plain text password is also saved to Database this time.
So now, in Database, your password is just "abc"

First, save() will return a reference of the instance which is just saved to Database, then user.set_password(user.password) is called. Please pay attention, user.password is your plain text raw password("abc"),

Second, set_password() will take this raw value and run some magic to encode it to secure password("imverycrazypassword"), which is ready to be stored in Database, then update the old plain text with the new one. However, this change is not committed to Database yet.

Third, user.save() is called, the "imverycrazypassword" is stored to your database.